# How can I sort the sub arrays from a multidimensional array by keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array for example:

```
$exampleArray = array (
                    array( 'Name' => 'Opony', 'Kod' =>'OPO',  'Price' => 100 ),
                    array( 'Kod' =>'OLE', 'Name' => 'Olej', 'Price' => 20 ),
                    array( 'Kod' =>'ABC', 'Price' => 20, 'Name' => 'abcdefg' )
                )
```

Keys in sub array are in random order. I want to sort the sub arrays by key:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Kod] => OPO
            [Name] => Opony
            [Price] => 100
        )
    [1] => Array
       (
            [Kod] => OLE
            [Name] => Olej
            [Price] => 20
       )
```

I try this:

```
function compr($x,$y){
  if($x == $y)
     return 0;
  elseif($x>$y)
     return 1;
  elseif($x<$y)
    return-1;
}

uksort($exampleArray, 'compr');

print_r($exampleArray);
```

But this code doesn't give me my expected result, what is wrong, how can I solve it?

Comment: The keys of that array are 0, 1, 2. I suspect uksort is not the function you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Ohh my poor english :(. I want to know how to use uksort() on multidemension arrays.

Comment: @MarcinJaworski Show your attempt how you tried to use `uksort`. Also add what your expected output would be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all of your inner Arrays [`by reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) and then just use [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) with [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) to sort your inner Arrays by the keys.

```
foreach($exampleArray as &$v) {
    uksort($v, function($a, $b){
        return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    });
}

unset($v); //So if you use $v later it doesn't change the last element of the array by reference
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Kod] => OPO
            [Name] => Opony
            [Price] => 100
        )
    //...
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Kod] => ABC
            [Name] => abcdefg
            [Price] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is ABSOLUTELY no reason to call a user-defined sorting algorithm (`uksort()`) here.

Just call `ksort()` on each row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VpiDN))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    ksort($row);
}
var_export($array);
```

Or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/liah9))

```
array_walk($array, fn(&$row) => ksort($row));
var_export($array);
```

Or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VaZkN))

```
function keySortRow(array $row): array {
    ksort($row);
    return $row;
}

var_export(
    array_map('keySortRow', $array)
);
```